# React code to display details not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to execute a simple react code to display details -

html -

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is the react code -

```
function User(props){
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.user_details.firstname}</h1>
    <h1>{props.user_details.lastname}</h1>
    <h1>{props.user_details.email}</h1>
  </div>  
  );  
}

function Address(props){
  return (
  <div>
      <h2>{props.address_details.city}</h2>                   <h2>{props.address_details.state}</h2>
      <h2>{props.address_details.zip}</h2>
  </div>    
  );
}

function Bundle(props){
  return (
  <div>
    <User user_details={props.user} />  
    <Address address_details={props.address} /> 
  </div>  
  );
}

const info = {
  user: {
    firstname: 'Arjun',
    lastname: 'G',
    email: 'aaaaaaaaa',
  },
  address: {
    city: 'bbbb',
    state: 'ccccc',
    zip: '333333',  
  },
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Bundle user={info.user} address={info.address} />, document.getElementById(root)
);
```

It's showing a blank page. I double checked and couldn't find the error. I am new to react and thought of going through the documentation and coding on codepen on the side. But I am stuck here. Please help

Comment: Is there any error log in console?

Comment: Typo `document.getElementById(root)` instead of `document.getElementById("root")`.

Comment: Yes, your code looks for a variable called `root`, as opposed to uses the text `"root"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the quotes around root

```
document.getElementById('root')
```

You should get an error saying

> Target container is not a DOM element.

Created A [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uwp1vo?file=index.js) for your solution